# Why tmux breaks my connections (ECONNABORTED)

Tags: tmux

I have a problem where when I run my node project from terminal outside tmux everything works find but when I run in inside the tmux i get the error `Error: read ECONNABORTED` for requests that my application makes to the my staging backend

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so it turned out that my company's VPN client was blocking requests coming from tmux. Hope it helps someone in the future

Comment: "my company's VPN client was blocking requests coming from tmux" – I'm curious about the actual mechanics behind this. I see no point in deliberate blocking traffic from programs running inside tmux (nor technical means to do so easily). For now the only thing I can think of is the environment. In tmux [it's not necessarily what you expect](https://superuser.com/a/1424154/432690).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).